# extract words from a string into different strings

Tags: r, string, split

I'm very new with coding, and I have to clean a table with string variables. One of the columns I'm trying to clean includes several variables in itself. So if I take one row from my column it looks like this

```
string<- ("'casual': True,'classy': False,'divey': False,'hipster': False,'intimate': False,'romantic': False,'touristy': False,'trendy': False,'upscale': False")
```

I'm trying to extract Boolean values for each of the categories into separate columns.So my outcome should have 9 columns(each for every category) and rows should include True/ False values.

What am I supposed to use in this case?

Comment: Are they always 9 categories in the same order separated by a `,`.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use `str_extract_all` to extract the word (`\\w+`) that succeeds a a space followed by a `:`

```
library(stringr)
as.logical(str_extract_all(string, "(?<=: )\\w+")[[1]])
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

If we need to parse into a data.frame, it would be better to use `fromJSON` from `jsonlite`

```
library(jsonlite)
lst1 <- fromJSON(paste0("{", gsub("'", "", gsub("\\b(\\w+)\\b",
           '"\\1"', string)), "}"))

data.frame(lapply(lst1, as.logical))
#   casual classy divey hipster intimate romantic touristy trendy upscale
#1   TRUE  FALSE FALSE   FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE  FALSE   FALSE
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
as.logical(regmatches(string, gregexpr("(?<=: )\\w+", string, perl = TRUE))[[1]])
```